# PHP returns different week number then system

Tags: php, time

I came across problem in PHP script that returns week number one higher then system does. In both situations timezone is set to "Europe/Prague".

I've done some tests. Both tests were performed on Debian 8.2 with PHP 5.6.14-0+deb8u1.

```
date +%W
```

result was: 43

```
echo date("W");
```

result was: 44

Comment: That's because the definition of week number is not singular. Obviously the system and PHP are using different definitions, so both are working as intended even if the results are not the same.

Comment: @Jon While I think this is mostly true, I do think that a week is defined the same between the two systems (7 days, 168hrs) ... the only difference here is where they start counting (0 or 1).

Comment: @MikelBitson: A week is fixed at 7 days, but when exactly the "first" week of a year begins [is not](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Week#Week_numbering).

Comment: @Jon Yes, however, both the PHP date function and the Linux date command start their weeks on Monday, with the first week of the year starting on the first Monday. So, in this case, they're treated the same just counted differently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
date +%W
```

Returns the week number from a zero index. (0-53)

```
echo date("W");
```

Returns the week number from a one index. (1-54)

This means that you'll always need to add one to the linux week or remove one from the php week to compare the two.

Answer (score 1):

Linux starts counting from week 0 as the first week.

PHP starts counting from week 1.

Thats why the linux-result is one less than the actual week we have now.